# The Team Explorer Solutions section does not show all available solutions

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfvc

I have 2 distincts project under TFS, they are located under different Source Control Folder.

1. **$/MyProject#1/DevBranch** -> *4 solutions (a,b,c,d) and 10 sub project (p1,p2,p3,etc.)*
2. **$/MyProject#2/DevBranch** -> *2 solutions (e,f) with one project each (p11,p12)*

In MyProject#1, my solution (a) need to reference the project (p11) that is under MyProject#2.

So I've created and mapped a Workspace that looks like this :

1. **$/MyProject#1/DevBranch** -> mapped to **C:\TFS\Project1**
2. **$/MyProject#2/DevBranch/SubFolder** -> mapped to **C:\TFS\Project1\p11**

The sub folder contains 1 solution (e) and one project (p11)

Once the "Get Latest Version" is complete, I am able to use the project (p11) under my solution (a) as expected.

My problem is that under the "Solutions" section of the "Team Explorer" window, I only see the solution of one folder at once.

If I open Visual Studio and select my newly created Workspace, I will only see the solution that is under **C:\TFS\Project1\p11**.

If I click "Open..." button of the solutions section and browse to the upper lever folder **C:\TFS\Project1** I will see all the solution from this folder but not the one of the sub folder. This is fine, I don't need the solution from the sub folder.

But, once I close Visual Studio and reopen, I will be back at the beginning where I only see one solution (e) and must click open each time I open Visual Studio.

Is there a way to set the root folder as the default one?

Thanks

Comment: Team Projects are intended to **isolate** resources. If you need to share things between Team Projects, then they shouldn't be in separate Team Projects. You could publish dependencies as NuGet packages and restore them in dependent applications. You could also map a single workspace at the Team Project Collection root, `$/`.

Comment: What is the advantage of a Workspace then?
Here is some background: Project #2 is a custom tool allowing communication between a file and a database. It include multiple project (front end, calculation engine, etc) and (p11) is an SQL Project that include every base tables/store procedure/etc needed by the tool to work on any database.
Project #1 is a customization for a new kind of file which use the base engine but that is not developed by the same team with a different project designer. The other team need to reference the sql project so they can publish were they want (client db)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether you have mapped the projects in one workspace. If you mapped them in one workspace, you'll see all solution files even though they under sub folder:

[image]

Comment: I did map the my project in my workspace as specified in my initial question. If I go under the "Source Control Explorer" window, select my workspace, i can see that the local folder is showing up correctly for each of them as stated here :

 $/MyProject#1/DevBranch -> mapped to C:\TFS\Project1
 $/MyProject#2/DevBranch/SubFolder -> mapped to C:\TFS\Project1\p11

Comment: Sorry that I missed information that you have your projects in two team projects. As you can connect one team project at once, you are not able to list projects across team projects. You need to move your related projects in the same team project.